# Using symbols in a directory name

Tags: server, directory, symbols

I know that on a PC you can use symbols ( all except `\/:*?"<>|` ) in a folder name, but does this apply to server directories?

I would like specifically use the + and - symbols as a name:

`example.com/-/subdirecotry`
`example.com/+/subdirectory`

Is this possible?

Also, what other symbols are available to use in this way?

Comment: Also note that an URL path is not required to be related to a folder path ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your OS, filesystem and your web server software. A common web server mirrors the directory structure. So if you are able to create the directory on your OS' filesystem your web server should be able to fetch it. It will use the URL encoding in some cases (question mark sign for example).

> I would like specifically use the + and - symbols as a name

This is for sure possible with a LAMP stack.

> all except `\/:*?"<>|`

Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_filename_limitations for more info on how this really works.

Comment: Thank you. Can you list any other symbols that are possible with a LAMP stack?

Comment: Linux(ext[2-4]): Any byte except `NUL` or `/`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814040/allowed-characters-in-filename

Comment: Thanks, that's a big help.